# Is ! operation atomic in JAVA

Tags: java, atomic, bytecode

```
if (!var) {...}
```

Does the above get expended into something like

- load value of var into register R
- set R = !R

Or its atomic where there is only a single operation

- load value of !var into register R

Comment: How do the two differ? What impact does it have if it's loaded into a register and negated? Logically there are two steps, but your code won't ever see that.

Comment: @shmosel that a thread will first keep a local value of not negated version and then negate it for the if comparison. If another thread is changing the value of var before the first thread negates it, it will be wrong.

Comment: No need to `set R = !R` because most architectures have compare equal and non-equal. Any way you're not writing `var` anywhere so it's not important for this to be atomic, and it's also impossible to do an atomic load if `var` is wider than the register size

Comment: @user1589188 That's not how concurrency works. Your thread might read the value, immediately negate it, and still execute the `if` after the value changes. Without synchronization, there is no concept of "now", there's just a state observed at some point in time. The behavior is correct with regard to that state. If the logic in your `if` depends on `var` remaining in a particular state, that needs to be enforced using some form of synchronization.

Comment: @shmosel Thanks! So the ! operation is atomic but since the `If` is not, what I worried can still happen.

Comment: It may or may not be atomic at the bytecode level. But it would have no impact on the correctness of your code or any other code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no bytecode level operation corresponding to logical not. It will typically get compiled as a branch, though the compiler can sometimes optimize that away.

For example, if you write code like `b = !a`, it would typically get compiled into something along the lines of

```
iload_0 ; load a
ifeq Lelse
iconst_0
goto Lend

Lelse:
iconst_1

Lend:
istore_1 ; store into B
```

**However** in the special case of `if (!var)` that you mentioned, this is not necessary. This is because the if instructions have variants for both regular and reversed conditions, i.e. instead of actually negating `var`, the compiler would just use the `ifne` instruction instead of the usual `ifeq`.

Edit: The above is how the code is compiled into bytecode. As far as synchronization goes, it is atomic for practical purposes. Since the code is purely local, there is ordinarily no way to observe side effects or for the calculation to interfere with other threads. Note that even if you load an unsynchronized field, the value becomes an intermediate value (i.e. a "register") and operations occur on that value, which is not shared among threads. No operation occurs directly on a field other than reads and writes.

That being said, since the code involves multiple bytecode instructions, you could stop a debugger in the middle of it. In that case, you could observe the intermediate state, although it would still have no effect on other threads.

Comment: So it is atomic then?

Comment: @user I expanded my answer to clarify.

Comment: Ok, so in my If case, it is atomic. But not otherwise?

Comment: @user1589188: your question simply makes no sense. You’re talking about registers, but registers are implementation specific details. The implementation executing this operation may consist of as many CPU instructions it wants, but there is no external observer, to which it would make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

No. It can't be.

Consider the following two scenarios:

```
Thread 1                Thread 2
--------                --------
Load A to register      ...
...                     Modify A
Invert register         ...
```

vs.

```
Thread 1                Thread 2
--------                --------
Atomically load !A      ...
    to register
...                     Modify A
```

The end result is the same -- in both cases, the register contains a value different from `!A`. The "atomic" nature of the load-inverted operation had absolutely no effect on the outcome.

If this seems like it could pose a problem, you probably need locking. Consider synchronizing on `A`, or on the container that it lives in.

Comment: Thanks for the visual graph. Dont forget there is an `if`. In your first case, the if block will be executed wrongly. While not in the second case, be thread 2 modify A before or after.

Comment: I'm confused by your comment. The `if` is implicitly the next operation in thread 1; it would be acting on the contents of the register, and would behave identically in either case.